# Is there a difference between declaring and constructing a value type object?

Tags: .net, vb.net, constructor, value-type

I've been working in .NET for some time now, but occasionally I still get confused by a disparity between the framework and my prior experience in C++.

In .NET, all objects are either value types or reference types. Reference types are allocated on the heap while value types are allocated on the stack (in the current CLR implementation, anyway). I get that. However, at least in VB.NET, you can still define a constructor on a value type. You can do this:

```
Public Structure Coordinates
    Public x As Integer
    Public y As Integer
    Public z As Integer

    Sub New(ByVal x As Integer, ByVal y As Integer, ByVal z As Integer)
        Me.x = x
        Me.y = y
        Me.z = z
    End Sub
End Structure
```

With this code in place, I can write `Dim c As Coordinates` and then access the members of `c` myself, or I can write `Dim c As New Coordinates(10, 20, 30)`. What is the difference between these two approaches? Obviously the `new` keyword is not allocating the object on the heap since it's a value type. I'm just not clear on whether constructors on value types are merely a convenience or if they actually *do* something other than execute like any other method.

To perhaps make my point clearer: I could easily have removed the definition for `New` in the above code, and still I could do this:

```
Dim c1 As Coordinates
Dim c2 As New Coordinates
```

Do these two lines do anything different?

---

**EDIT**: Guffa has pointed out that declaring and constructing are *not* the same. The following code demonstrates this:

```
For i As Integer = 1 To 3
    Dim c1 As Coordinates
    Dim c2 As New Coordinates

    c1.x += 1
    c2.x += 1

    Console.WriteLine("c1.x = {0}, c2.x = {1}", c1.x, c2.x)
Next

' output: '
' c1.x = 1, c2.x = 1 '
' c1.x = 2, c2.x = 1 '
' c1.x = 3, c2.x = 1 '
```

So, **in a scenario involving iteration, local variables representing value types are not re-allocated on the stack**; they stay put. I took a look at this same scenario using plain old integers and found the same behavior:

```
For i As Integer = 1 To 3
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim y As New Integer

    x += 1
    y += 1

    Console.WriteLine("x = {0}, y = {1}", x, y)
Next

' output: '
' x = 1, y = 1 '
' x = 2, y = 1 '
' x = 3, y = 1 '
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the New keyword in the declaration like this:

```
Dim c2 As New Coordinates
```

is just a shortcut for:

```
Dim c2 As Coordinates = New Coordinates()
```

The parameterless constructor is automatically created for the structure, and it just returns a value with all properites set to their default value (i.e. all bytes zeroed out), functionally equivalent to:

```
Public Sub New()
   x = 0
   y = 0
   z = 0
End Sub
```

In VB all local variables are initialized when you enther the method, so the variable c1 declared without the New keyword will also be zeroed out. The difference is not visible until you execute the statement more than once:

```
For i As Integer = 1 to 3
   Dim c1 As Coordinates
   Dim c2 As New Coordinates
   c1.x += 1
   c2.x += 1
   Console.WriteLine("c1.x = {0}, c2.x = {1}", c1.x, c2.x)
Next
```

Output:

```
c1.x = 1, c2.x = 1
c1.x = 2, c2.x = 1
c1.x = 3, c2.x = 1
```

The c1 variable is initialized only once, while the c2 variable is initialized each time the statement is executed.

As a structure value can exist without a constructor being called first, the structure constructor is mostly a convenient way of initializing the structure. It's neater than a static method that creates a structure value, but it works pretty much the same:

```
Public Shared Function Create(ByVal x As Integer, ByVal y As Integer, ByVal z As Integer) As Coordinates
   Dim item As Coordinates
   item.x = x
   item.y = y
   item.z = z
   Return item
End Function

Dim c3 As Coordinates = Coordinates.Create(1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: Well that is very interesting indeed... This is certainly an eye-opener.

Answer (score 2):

There is always a default (parameterless) constructor for a struct (It's an error to declare it).

### for VB.Net (EDIT)

it's the same ;), see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2hkbth2a%28VS.71%29.aspx)

### for C#:

The difference between `Coordinates c1;` and `Coordinates c2 = New Coordinates();` is that for the 1st one struct fields remain unassigned and the object can not be used until all fields are initialized. The 2nd one initialize all fields within the struct object.

For more info go [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ah19swz4%28VS.71%29.aspx), it's well detailed.

Comment: Maybe there is a difference between the syntactical rules of C# versus VB.NET? You can access the members of a `Structure` in VB.NET after having only declared it. See my edit.

Comment: You're right; I edited my answer to be more explicit about the difference.

Comment: @najmeddine: To be fair, I was pretty sure the rules were different, and I half-predicted that someone would come along and provide an answer from a C# perspective with the assumption that they were the same. It's definitely something useful to be aware of, especially for someone like me who uses both languages.

Comment: In C#, the statement `c2 = new Coordinates();` will initialize all fields, but the statement `c2 = new Coordinates(someParams);` might not necessarily do so.  If the parameterized constructor calls a virtual method which passes `this` as an `out` parameter to a virtual method, and if that method is overridden in a language which doesn't recognize `out` parameters, it's possible that the statement `c2 = new Coordinates(parameters);` may not modify `c2` at all.

Answer (score 1):

In VB.Net,

```
Dim c1 As Coordinates
Dim c2 As New Coordinates
```

do exactly the same. In C#, trying to use c1.X would give a compiler (unassigned) error whereas c2.X would be 0.

This follows from the VB rule that local variables are default set to 0 (or 0.0 or false or ...) and in C# they are considered unassigned.

The rules for constructors are different for structs and classes, you cannot add:

```
 Sub New()
    Me.x = 1
    Me.y = 2
    Me.z = 3
 End Sub
```

because this constructor is 'reserved'.

Comment: So value type constructors are provided purely for convenience, then?

Comment: Dan, more or less. They provide a convenient way to initialize but calling them is optional.

Comment: OK then, that works for me. I'm sure you can understand how this is counterintuitive for me as a former C++ developer, though.

Comment: -1. The two declarations does *not* do exactly the same. (See my answer for an explanation.)

Comment: Guffa, you are right, a loop shows c2 is actually overwritten with a new instance. Dan can change if he wants to.

Comment: Sorry @Henk, it's still a good answer... looks like Guffa's right that they are not quite the same, though. Very educational.